# Silverlight - How do I make the Listbox selection region the same shape as the list box item

Tags: silverlight

I am using a Listbox with a the ItemsPanelTemplate set to a Canvas. This is so I can position Polygons on the canvas and still have them selectable. The problem I am having is the selection region is not shaped to the same size as the polygon (it is a rectangular shape that covers the extent of the polygon)

```
<ListBox Name="LayoutList" ItemsSource="{Binding LayoutItems}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LayoutItemStyle}">
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas x:Name="LayoutCanvas" Background="Beige">
        </Canvas>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Polygon Points="{Binding Points}" Stroke="{Binding Stroke}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

The selection region is determined by the item container; I'm not certain, but you might be able to do what you want by modifying the ListBox.ItemContainerStyle (instead of or in addition to the DataTemplate). Something like this:

```
<ListBox>

<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Polygon Points="{Binding Points}" Stroke="{Binding Stroke}" StrokeThickness="1"/>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this but the selection regions are still rectangular. I am continuing to experiment. :-(